# Vue.js component data depends on other component data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a component as follows.

```
export default {
    name: "ImagesGallery",
    data () {
        return {
            activeImageIndex: 0,
        };
    },
}
```

This component is a gallery of images.
Now I have another component in which I need to refer to the activeImageIndex.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <images-gallery ref="gallery">
    </div>
</template>

export default {
     name: "AnotherComponent",
     components: {
         ImagesGallery,
     },
     data () {
        return {
            imageIndex: null, // I want this to refer to the images gallery index.
        };
     },
}
```

What I want to achieve:

I want the "imageIndex" of the other component to be a reference to the "activeImageIndex" of the ImagesGallery component. If I modify "imageIndex", also the value of the gallery index should change.

I tried to assign imageIndex: this.$refs.gallery.activeImageIndex in the data function but obviously it doesn't works in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the index to the child component as a prop:

** PARENT

```
<images-gallery :activeImageIndex="imageIndex" ref="gallery">
```

** CHILD

```
export default {
    name: "ImagesGallery",
    props: {activeImageIndex: Number} 
}
```

In the child component you can access `activeImageIndex` the same way as you did previously.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about reactivity, props and the **v-model** directive in VueJs.
You should pass **imageIndex** to a child component as a prop using v-model.
For instance:

```
export default {
    name: "ImagesGallery",
    props: {
      value: Number // this prop represents **imageIndex** from a parent component.
    }
}
```

and a parent:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <images-gallery ref="gallery" v-model="imageIndex">
    </div>
</template>
...
```

To change **imageIndex** in the child component you should call:

```
this.$emit('input', newIndex)
```

To change **imageIndex** in the parent component you can just assign it:

```
this.imageIndex = newIndex
```